# How to return from a function multiple variables?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Edit:

Ultimately I want to print out something like this:
Scooter has 3 materials: "wood", "metal", "glass"; Baseball bat has two materials: "wood", metal" **only using a for loop.**

I'm using the following:

```
var data = [
    {
     "title": "scooter", 
     "materials": ["wood", "metal", "glass"]
    }, 
   {
    "title": "baseball bat", 
    "materials": ["wood", "metal"]
   },
  {
    "title": "coffee table", 
    "materials": ["wood"]
  }];
```

I thought I could do a simple pass through with a for loop to get the title, count, and create an array with something like this:

```
 function testing () {
   let items = []; //contains the titles
   let container = []; //contains the materials
   let count = 0; //count of items
   for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    if (data[i].materials.length > 2){
    container.push(data[i].materials); 
    count = data[i].materials.length;
    items.push(data[i].title)
   }
  }return container;
 }
console.log(testing);
```

I don't know if the code is correct to get what I want out. Any thoughts?

Edit: So when I run this code I'm simply getting the list of the materials. When doing a return items and console.log(testing); I'm getting a list of the items.

It also looks like the count is just getting an array count of the titles not of the materials.

Further Edit with additional code:

```
function testing () {
  let items = []; 
  let container = []; 
  let count = 0; 
  let result = '';
   for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    if (data[i].materials.length > 2){
      container.push(data[i].materials); 
      items.push(data[i].title)
       for (let j=0; j<container.length; j++){
        result= `${items[j]} has materials :${container[j]}`;
       }
     }
   }return result;
 }
console.log(testing());
```

With the above I can get the last title to show that meets the if statement with a list of items. I'm not however able to get a count of the materials. So for example it's simply showing:
Baseball bat has materials wood, metal

The question I'm facing then is how do I get the count and then display all objects that match. So it would be instead:
Scooter has 3 materials that are: wood, metal, glass
Baseball bat has 2 materials that are: wood, metal

Comment: Well, what happened when you tried to run this?

Comment: *"I don't know if the code is correct to get what I want out."* Well, does it or doesn't it? Are you running into a problem? If so, *what* problem?

Comment: Your codes a little hard to read, but yes. If you want to return multiple values, you need to store all the values in some container. Instead of putting them in a list, you could also just store them in a JavaScript object.

Comment: You can return only a single value from a function, that may be an object or array, ofcourse. But why to bother? Build the string in the function, and return that string to print.

Comment: We need more detail:
 exact output you are looking for; 
 exact *actual* code you've used; 
 problems/errors you encounter

Comment: The exact output I'm looking for is:
Scooter has 3 materials:
-wood
-metal
-glass

Baseball bat has 2 materials: 
-wood
-metal

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you don't really need for loop. Arrays have map method, which can apply your function to each element of the array.

```js
var data = [
    {
     "title": "scooter", 
     "materials": ["wood", "metal", "glass"]
    }, 
   {
    "title": "baseball bat", 
    "materials": ["wood", "metal"]
   },
  {
    "title": "coffee table", 
    "materials": ["wood"]
  }];
 
var result = data.map(item => `${item.title} has ${item.materials.join(', ')}`).join('\n') 
console.log(result);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Except I'm trying to learn through using the for loop process. Otherwise your code would be right on the spot.

Comment: Also it ignores the if statement to focus only on those with a length greater than 2.

Answer (score 0):

See if the below code helps you in any way:

```
console.log(data.map(item => `${item.title} has ${item.materials.join(', ')}`).join('\n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is map each of the items and concatenate the formatted strings.

You will need to know the count of the materials to display the quantity.

```js
const capitalize = s => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substr(1);
const quantity = x => 'one,two,three,four,...'.split(',')[x - 1];

var data = [{
    "title": "scooter",
    "materials": ["wood", "metal", "glass"]
  }, {
    "title": "baseball bat",
    "materials": ["wood", "metal"]
  }, {
    "title": "coffee table",
    "materials": ["wood"]
  }
];

console.log(data.map(item => {
  return [
    capitalize(item.title),
    ' has ',
    quantity(item.materials.length),
    ' material' + (item.materials.length > 1 ? 's' : '') + ': ',
    item.materials.map(material => {
      return '"' + material + '"';
    }).join(', ')
  ].join('');
}).join('; '));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to write a `function`, that works for one `object` inside your array. If this works you can simple call this function inside a `for-loop` and push it to an array or use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which returns an `array` by default.

### The Function

```
function createConstructionKit(object) {
    var matarials = object.materials.join('", "') // this will give you for the first case -> wood", "metal", "glass
    var title = object.title // no logic -> just did it to have lesser to write in the next line..
    var capitilizedTitle = title.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + title.slice(1) // capitilize the first one and return all letters off the first index
    return capitilizedTitle + ' has ' + object.materials.length + ' materials: "' + matarials + '"'
}
```

### Solution with Map

```
var buildingInstructionsdata = data.map(function(object) {
    return createConstructionKit(object)
})
```

### Solution with a Loop

```
var buildingInstructionsdata = []
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    buildingInstructionsdata.push(createConstructionKit(data[i]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first,

```
console.log(testing);
```

is just going to return the text of the function, you have to run the function, like this

```
console.log(testing());
```

Here's my function, written is ES6:

```
var data = [
    {
     "title": "scooter", 
     "materials": ["wood", "metal", "glass"]
    }, 
   {
    "title": "baseball bat", 
    "materials": ["wood", "metal"]
   },
  {
    "title": "coffee table", 
    "materials": ["wood"]
  }];

function newTestingES6() {
  let printStr = '';
  for (let obj of data) { 
    printStr = `${obj.title} has ${obj.materials.length} materials: ${[...obj.materials]}`
    console.log(printStr);      
  }

  return 1;
}

function runTest() {
  console.log(newTestingES6());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was what I ended up getting to work:

```
 function testing () {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   if (data[i].materials.length >2) {
    console.log(`${data[i].title} has ${data[i].materials.length} 
 materials:`);
    for (let j = 0; j < data[i].materials.length; j++) {
     const material = data[i].materials[j];
     console.log("- " + material);
      }
   }
   }
 }
console.log(testing());
```